# Object with multiple inheritance sharing one resource - looking for good design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, microcontroller

Hope this has not been answered before, I found it very hard to find a snappy description of my problem.

I'm about to write a C++ API that should compile on microcontroller as well as on PC targets which abstracts communication with some hardware device. The operation modes of the device and with that the parameters to control might change at runtime while the connection stays the same. The connection is managed by a separate class, to which my base class instance has a protected reference. A basic device looks like that (simplified example):

```
class DeviceBase
{
public:
    void setOnOffState (bool onOff);
    bool getOnOffState();
protected:
    DeviceBase (Connection& c);
    Connection& connection;
}

DeviceBase::DeciveBase (Connection& c) : connection (c) {};
void DeviceBase::setOnOffState (bool onOff) {connection.sendParameter (/* Parameter number for onOff */, onOff); };
bool DeviceBase::getOnPffState() {return connection.requestParameter (/* Parameter number for onOff */); };
```

Now there are some generic device types which all share a basic parameter set. Let's say there is generic type 1 which always has parameterA and parameterB and generic type 2 which always has parameterC and parameterD. So their implementation could look like this:

```
class GenericDeviceType1 : public DeviceBase
{
public:
    void setParameterA (int parameterA);
    int getParameterA();
    void setParameterB (char parameterB);
    char getParameterB();
protected:
    GenericDeviceType1 (Connection& c);
}

GenericDeviceType1::GenericDeviceType1 (Connection& c) : DeviceBase (c) {};
void GenericDeviceType1::setParameterA (int parameterA) {connection.sendParameter (/* Parameter number for parameterA */, parameterA); };
int  GenericDeviceType1::getParameterA() {return connection.requestParameter (/* Parameter number for parameterA */); };
//... and so on - I think you got the principle
```

But it gets even more complicated. There are specific flavors of each type. But some share some groups of parameters. Now what I'd ideally like to do is to build them up with multiple inheritance like this:

```
class DeviceType1ParameterSetX // a device with parameters E and F
{
public:
    void setParameterE (float parameterE);
    float getParameterE();
    void setParameterF (int parameterF);
    int getParameterF();
}

class DeviceType1ParameterSetY // a device with parameters G and H
{
public:
    void setParameterG (bool parameterG);
    bool getParameterG();
    void setParameterH (char parameterH);
    char getParameterH();
}

class DeviceType1ParameterSetZ // a device with parameters I and J
{
public:
    void setParameterI (int parameterI);
    int getParameterI();
    void setParameterJ (int parameterJ);
    int getParameterJ();
}

class SpecificDeviceType11 : public GenericDeviceType1,
                             public DeviceType1ParameterSetX,
                             public DeviceType1ParameterSetZ
{
public:
    SpecificDeviceType11 (Connection &c);
    //...
}

class SpecificDeviceType12 : public GenericDeviceType1,
                             public DeviceType1ParameterSetX,
                             public DeviceType1ParameterSetY,
                             public DeviceType1ParameterSetZ
{
public:
    SpecificDeviceType12 (Connection &c);
    //...
}
```

Problem with this approach: The classes `DeviceTypeNParameterSetM` don't know anything about the connection, so implementing their setter and getter functions invoking the connection instance is not directly possible. However, I really would like to avoid making the connection member of the base class public to keep the api clean. I know that I could store a reference to the connection in each parameter set class, but that seems like a waste of memory to me, regarding the fact that this should be able run on a microcontroller with a small memory footprint and without the possibility of dynamic memory management. So ideally the memory footprint of each specific instance should be the same.

Now my question is: How could a solution resulting in a clean public API look like? I'm looking forward to some inspiration! As a side information: There will be some 150 different specific device flavors in the end, so I'd really like to keep it as organized and user-friendly as possible!

Comment: can you just create a separate class for the shared connection and then simply inject it to those that need it? all classes needing it should implement an method like ‘set connection’ etc... or the flavored classes could register with the class that manages the shared conn

Comment: One could create a static connection instance in the base class.  That makes it auto shared between each derived class.  The parameter base class could have have a a reference to the connection set at object construction time.

Comment: A single static connection instance wouldn't suit here, as there might be multiple devices each with their own connection as well as multiple devices sharing one connection. With each parameterSet class from the example above having it own reference to the connection I see the difficulty of `sizeof (SpecificDeviceType11)` (2 references) being different to `sizeof (SpecificDeviceType12)` (3 references) so on a microcontroller without the ability to dynamically allocate memory this would lead to the problem of not knowing how much space on the stack to pre-allocate for putting the objects there.

Comment: " this should be able run on a microcontroller with a small memory footprint" Then don't use intricate inheritance schemes or multiple inheritance. You need to simplify the OOP design and dependences. Don't write a single line of code until the design is simple and sensible. Then from there pick which language that would do the job best. In case on microcontrollers it is almost certainly C, even though implementing an OOP design in C is more painful than in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of doing this is to make the DeviceBase base class `public virtual` and including it as a `public virtual` base class of all various ParameterSet classes that need to know about it.  Then any of them can access the connection if they need to.

When you use virtual inheritance like this, you need to explicit initialize the `DeviceBase` base class in every non-abstract class's constructors, but that is not too difficult.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about virtual inheritance until now! Would this also work with DeviceBase having a virtual member function that is overridden by the GenericDeviceType classes (--> non-virtual inheritance of DeviceBase) but not by the ParameterSet classes (--> virtual inheritance of DeviceBase)?

Comment: Just played around a bit with this pattern. While it really helps to achieve the clean interface I'm looking for it still results in Objects with multiple virtual inheritances having a bigger memory footprint than the base class, according to some simple `sizeof` calls. Anyway, I could find a way around this if neccesarry

Comment: Did some more tests and found out that every additional virtual inheritance seems to increase the size of the Object by 8 Bytes. So this is not really suitable for my use case, even if your answer looked really promising in the first place

Comment: @PluginPenguin: Sounds like a broken compiler -- maybe find a better one?  virtual inheritance should only increase the size of the vtable, never the size of the objects.

Comment: I don't think my compiler is broken. Just tested [this](https://gist.github.com/JanosGit/f3e4ddd493e9bdd3fcaa27fe65a6c3c4) little gist I set up for testing this with an up-to-date Xcode release (Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)) - wouldn't expect this setup to be broken as a first explanation for my observations.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt is actually sub-optimal (see the edit history if you are interested in that). It is in fact not possible to do multiple inheritance and keep the size of the derived class the same as the "real" Base class, since each parent class must have a distinct address (even if all but one 
parent class is empty).

You can instead use tailed inheritance like this:

```
struct Connection {
    template<class T>
    void sendParameter(int,T); // implemented somewhere
    template<class T>
    T requestParameter(int);   // implemented somewhere
};

class DeviceBase {
public:
    void setOnOffState(bool onOff) { connection.sendParameter(0, onOff); }
    bool getOnOffState()           { return connection.requestParameter<bool>(0); }
protected:
    DeviceBase(Connection& c) : connection(c) {}
    template<class T>
    void sendParameter(int i,T t) { connection.sendParameter(i,t); }
    template<class T>
    T requestParameter(int i) { return connection.requestParameter<T>(i); }
private:
    Connection& connection;
};

template<class Base>
class DeviceType1ParameterSetX : public Base // a device with parameters A and B
{
public:
    void setParameterA (float parameterA) { this->sendParameter(0xA, parameterA);}
    float getParameterA()                 { return  this->template requestParameter<float>(0xA);}
    void setParameterB (int parameterB)   { this->sendParameter(0xB, parameterB);}
    int getParameterB()                   { return  this->template requestParameter<int>(0xB);}

    DeviceType1ParameterSetX(Connection& c) : Base(c) {}

};

template<class Base>
class DeviceType1ParameterSetY : public Base // a device with parameters C and D
{
public:
    void setParameterC (float parameterC) { this->sendParameter(0xC, parameterC);}
    float getParameterC()                 { return  this->template requestParameter<float>(0xC);}
    void setParameterD (int parameterD)   { this->sendParameter(0xD, parameterD);}
    int getParameterD()                   { return  this->template requestParameter<int>(0xD);}
    DeviceType1ParameterSetY(Connection& c) : Base(c) {}
};

template<class Base>
class DeviceType1ParameterSetZ : public Base // a device with parameters E and F
{
public:
    void setParameterE (float parameterE) { this->sendParameter(0xE, parameterE);}
    float getParameterE()                 { return  this->template requestParameter<float>(0xE);}
    void setParameterF (int parameterF)   { this->sendParameter(0xF, parameterF);}
    int getParameterF()                   { return  this->template requestParameter<int>(0xF);}
    DeviceType1ParameterSetZ(Connection& c) : Base(c) {}

};

class SpecificDeviceTypeXZ : public 
        DeviceType1ParameterSetX<
        DeviceType1ParameterSetZ<
            DeviceBase> >
{
public:
    SpecificDeviceTypeXZ (Connection &c) : DeviceType1ParameterSetX(c) {}
    //...
};


class SpecificDeviceTypeXY : public 
        DeviceType1ParameterSetX<
        DeviceType1ParameterSetY<
            DeviceBase> >
{
public:
    SpecificDeviceTypeXY (Connection &c) : DeviceType1ParameterSetX(c) {}
    //...
};

void foo(Connection& c)
{
    SpecificDeviceTypeXY xy(c);
    SpecificDeviceTypeXZ xz(c);
    static_assert(sizeof(xy)==sizeof(void*), "xy must just contain a reference");
    static_assert(sizeof(xz)==sizeof(void*), "xz must just contain a reference");
    xy.setOnOffState(true);
    xy.setParameterC(1.0f);
    xz.setParameterF(xy.getParameterB());
}
```

I somewhat simplified your example to save some typing (e.g., I left out `GenericDeviceType1` which would essentially be a `DeviceType1ParameterSetX<DeviceBase>` in my example), and the names/numbers don't match your example.

To play around here is a godbolt-Link (confirming that the size does not grow): https://godbolt.org/z/BtNOe_
Here, `rdi` will hold the first pointer parameter (which most of the time is the implicit `this` parameter), or the pointer implied by the `Connection& c` parameter of `foo`. `esi` will always hold the parameter number `i` (since it is the first integer parameter to the methods of `Connection`, and depending on the type, the next parameter (of the `sendParameter` calls) will be passed via `xmm0` or `edx`. The return value will be in `eax` for integers and in `xmm0` for floats (that is all assuming x86_64bit ABI).

To understand what happens I also recommend to insert some debug-outputs (like `cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' ' << this << '\n';`) at several places.

Adding data members (or methods) at any stage should be save (of course it will increase the size).